# ListView item not playing audio at the selected index

Tags: android, listview

When I click on each and individual cell, it plays the current song at index 0. 
How would you fetch the current string to the current position on the ListView item click, then play it?

To make it clearer here is a example what this code does:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWaXv.png)

Any suggestions and help is appreciated.

Code:

```
//
private static  final int my_permission = 1;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    Uri songUri;

    int songLocation;
    int songArtist;
    int songTitle;
    ////
    String currentLocation;
    String currentArtist;
    String currentTitle;
    //
    Cursor songCursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
            {
                 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                         new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, my_permission);
            }
            else
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, my_permission);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            doStuff();
        }
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        getMusic();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentLocation.toString() + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(currentLocation.toString()));
                    mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public void getMusic()
    {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        songCursor = contentResolver.query(songUri, null, null, null, null);

        if (songCursor != null && songCursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            songTitle = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            songArtist = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            songLocation = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

            do {
                currentTitle = songCursor.getString(songTitle); //
                currentArtist = songCursor.getString(songArtist); //
                currentLocation = songCursor.getString(songLocation);
                arrayList.add("Title: " + currentTitle + "\n" + "Artist: " + currentArtist + "\n" + "Location: " + currentLocation);
            }
            while (songCursor.moveToNext());
            {

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode){
            case my_permission:{

                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        doStuff();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
//

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                String musicPath = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), musicPath  + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(musicPath ));
                    mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting music path from `ContntResolver` through `Cursor`, so If your Cursor only references one row, you may call moveToFirst() on it before reading data to ensure that you are on a valid index. Both moveToFirst() and moveToNext() have the same effect when the Cursor is first created and is at index -1.

so just change this

```
 if (songCursor != null && songCursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        songTitle = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        songArtist = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        songLocation = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);


        while (songCursor.moveToNext());
        {

            currentTitle = songCursor.getString(songTitle); //
            currentArtist = songCursor.getString(songArtist); //
            currentLocation = songCursor.getString(songLocation);
            arrayList.add("Title: " + currentTitle + "\n" + "Artist: " + 
            currentArtist + "\n" + "Location: " + currentLocation);
        }
    }
```

Happy coding!!